# Переоткрытие после устранения всех недостатков или только причины закрытия?

Tags: обсуждение, переоткрытие-вопросов

Какой-то вопрос содержит несколько причин для закрытия. Он был закрыт по одной из них. После этого эта причина была исправлена, но не были исправлены другие.

Надо ли переоткрывать вопрос, чтобы закрыть его по другой причине, ведь теперь показываемая автору причина устарела? Или надо ждать устранения всех причин для переоткрытия? Или что-то другое?

[Пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178846/398802)

Comment: Странно, что взаимоисключающие ответы заминусованы. Непонятно, что делать тогда :)

Comment: Нет, его не надо было пероткрывать. В комментариях были указаны недостатки. ТС их не устранил. Комментариев от него не было, т.е. он понял, что надо сделать, но не сделал.

Comment: @0xdb можете добавить это в соответствующий общий ответ или дать свой, чтобы можно было голосвать за него

Comment: Как-то не уютно под заминусованным ответом публиковаться. Заминусовали их помоему за то, что их автор вместо развёрнутого ответа (ведь он "виновник" этой темы) устроил опросник, который не плохо было бы удалить.

Comment: Ответ, я полагаю, можно найти в предупреждении об отзыве голоса за закрытие. При голосовании за закрытии вопроса можно выбрать только одну причину. После исправления именно этого недостатка можно голос отозвать - но больше нельзя голосовать за закрытие по второй причине. То есть сама система требует устранения ВСЕХ недостатков, а не только одного выбранного, чтобы можно было с чистой совестью отозвать голос. С другой стороны, только одна, самая популярная, причина отображается автору - и после исправления именно её он и дальше будет в непонятках... в общем, вряд ли есть однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В текущем виде вопрос соответствует требованиям сайта, а значит должен быть открыт. Только метко [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) надо было добавить.

И вообще, раз уж автор показал, что готов править вопрос, то можно с ним общаться в комментариях при открытом вопросе, а не закрывать-открывать постоянно.

Comment: Вопрос касается не только этого конкретного вопроса, а таких ситуаций в целом. Кстати, я не согласен, что он соответствует требованиям сайта: это явно учебное задание без чётких условий (непонятно, что такое совершенное число и какой диапазон чисел) и попыток решения (указаны были 4 самых популярных языка, чтобы привлечь максимальное внимание)